# How to leverage a stored XSS to perform a file inclusion?

Tags: web-application, xss, file-inclusion

I have identified a stored XSS and I'm wondering, how could I leverage that vulnerability to upload a shell.

Comment: What is the web app platform? If it is PHP, did you try to use simple phpinfo function as stored value?

Comment: @Kasun it's php. It seems that I can inject any HTML but not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSS is a client side attack, but it can sometimes be used to leverage a bigger attack against the server.

Say there was a page that the admin user only had access to as the first thing it does was to check the user has appropriate permissions.

e.g. `http://www.example.com/admin/delete_user.php?id=3&lang=en`

It might be that the `lang` parameter points to a PHP include file:

```
include($_GET['lang'].'.php');
```

In which case the attacker could embed the string

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/admin/delete_user.php?id=3&lang=../../uploads/foo" />
```

in order to include the `foo.php` that the attacker has managed to get onto the server (by other means, such as file upload functionality that was thought to be secure as it uploaded outside the web root) and gain file execution, or even a reverse shell. The file would be included and executed whenever an admin accessed the page containing the stored XSS vulnerability. Alternatively, a remote file may be included using a URL (e.g. in PHP if [allow-url-include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) is enabled).

This very much depends on the site in question, and in this case the attacker would need to have knowledge that such a LFI (or RFI) vulnerability existed. This is not such a leap, as many applications are open source so an attacker would be able to install their own local copy in order to investigate such weaknesses.

Comment: I have checked all includes/requires/fopen but no one is accepting dynamically files, they are all hard-coded. So I think that using this XSS to upload a shell won't be possible. Anyway, I think that is another question and this one is already answered

Answer (score 1):

XSS is an attack against the *client*, not the server.

The only way an attacker could turn this against the server is if the victim has special privileges (like an administrator account).

Answer (score -1):

You can't. By using [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) techniques, you can only retrieve information from clients.